# PHP Mysqli select two DISTINCT from data base

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch two different DISTINCT values from data base am not able to do that that gives me an error. I don't want both to be combined in as statement and fetch as one I need individual DISTINCT values.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT AttendanceID from attendance_master where Attendence_taken_by !='admi' at line 1\

My Query

```
$query = "select DISTINCT Standard , DISTINCT AttendanceID  from attendance_master where  Attendence_taken_by !='$admin'  and  SchoolID='$schoolid' and AttendanceDate >= '$tfrom_date' and AttendanceDate <= '$tto_date' ";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<table><tr>".$row["Standard"]."</tr><tr>".$row["AttendanceID"]."</tr></table>";
}
```

Comment: You can try just using a single `DISTINCT` keyword.  What are your desired results?  Can you show us some sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax of `DISTINCT` is

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

So change your query with

```
$query = "select DISTINCT Standard , AttendanceID  from attendance_master.....
```

Instead of assign direct value use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)